# Android: Cannot execute more than one Internet process at the same time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient

I am developing an Android application, but I have problem. When I execute a process from Internet via async task, I cannot run another Internet process from different thread at the same time. The other process does not start until first one ends. Async tasks start, but http requests wait for the other one.

How can I handle this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using `execute()` to run your `AsyncTask`. Quoting [the `AsyncTask` JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Or, use an HTTP library that offers asynchronous operation as part of the library itself, like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).